# AdSense on WordPress Plugin Option Page

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

Does anybody know whether it is okey to put adsense ads on WordPress plugin option pages? Somebody told me that it's a violation of adsence's terms but I cannot find which one talks about it in [here](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You acknowledge and agree that Ads and/or Links: (i) shall only be
>   displayed in connection with the Property(ies), each of which is
>   subject to review and approval by Google in its discretion at any time

[AdSense Terms and Conditions](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms)

Given that you would not know in advance which properties would display your ads and, even if you did, you would not be able to grant Google access to review the ads' placement (because it would be in others' secured administration areas) it does not appear as though including AdSense ads with your plugin would be allowed by the AdSense terms and conditions.

Comment: I would say which properties would display is clear. However, indeed, Google may not have access to the administration panel of each site. That sounds like, AdSense cannot be placed in SNS in general that requires login. Thanks for looking into the documentation.